# iOS UITableView: Automatically or best way to update/insert/delete data

Tags: ios, database, uitableview, fmdb

I have a database that is constantly changing (new updated records, new inserted records, deleted records, records being placed in a certain order,ect).  I am wondering if there is a way to update my UITableView automatically when new items are being inserted, delete, updated etc in my database. Basically always match the table view array data source to my database.  So far, the best way I found and most consistent is to fetch the data from my database again and reload the tableview.

Any tips or suggestions is appreciated.

Edit: I am using SQL lite and FMBD wrapper.

Comment: And you're not using Core Data, I assume?

Comment: Correct, I am using an SQL wrapper called FMBD.

Comment: Then fetching the data and reloading the table view is the best approach. If it's a large table and you want to reduce the amount of work done each time the data is updated, you can calculate only the rows that should be changed and update them, and/or call `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` on the table view before and after you do the calculations.

Comment: The biggest problem is I need the table view to be in a certain order. The order can be constantly change. For example, the order can be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 however it can change to 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1. So keep track of these order can be a pain. Thats why I just grab the data from database again and reload.

Comment: It seems NRitH is right about just reloading tableview.

Comment: @Weakman10122 Yes you just want to reload tableview on update of database...